# How to wait for full page load using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a site using Python with Beautifulsoup, but the site takes a long time to load and the scraping is fast and doesn't recover completely. I would like to know how to wait 5 seconds before retrieving the source code using Beautifulsoup.

I think a code is like this:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

url = 'https://www.edocente.com.br/pnld/2020/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}

req = Request(url, headers = headers)
response = urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll('a', class_="btn bold mt-4 px-5")
```

I can't recovery a whole source code because site is slow to load and my tags aren´t recovered. How to wait to recover the whole source code from site?

I would like to get only the text of the href tags, as below:

```
<a href="/pnld/2020/obra/companhia-das-ciencias-6-ano-saraiva" class="btn bold mt-4 px-5">Ver Obra </a>
<a href="/pnld/2020/obra/companhia-das-ciencias-7-ano-saraiva" class="btn bold mt-4 px-5">Ver Obra </a>
<a href="/pnld/2020/obra/companhia-das-ciencias-8-ano-saraiva" class="btn bold mt-4 px-5">Ver Obra </a>
```

I'd like to recovery:

```
/pnld/2020/obra/companhia-das-ciencias-6-ano-saraiva
/pnld/2020/obra/companhia-das-ciencias-7-ano-saraiva
/pnld/2020/obra/companhia-das-ciencias-8-ano-saraiva
```

How to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i guess at this url (`https://www.edocente.com.br/pnld/2020/`) there is a `dynamic` website. meaning that you `cant` load dynamic websites with `requests` or `urllib`.

for loading dynamic websites and then save them to beautiful soup you need to use a browser to load the website in the background. there are libaries for doing that.

here is a snippet to load dynamic websites

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def get_dynamic_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content(), "html.parser")
        browser.close()
        return soup
```

install the python package

```sh
pip install playwright
```

then install the chromium browser (in your terminal)

```sh
(shell prompt) > playwright install
```

and you are ready to scrape dynamic websites.

Comment: Good, but I am running it in jupyter-notebook (google colab) and I can't install this one:
# playwright install
How to do?

Comment: To use install commands (Google colab): `!pip install playwright`

Comment: Error: It looks like you are using Playwright Sync API inside the asyncio loop.
Please use the Async API instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get a page *asynchronously* using `aiohttp` and `asyncio`. For example let’s pass that `url` to query and `headers` as parameters to `ClientSession` instance, now we have a `ClientResponse` object called `resp` and you can get all the information you need from the response.

install modules by: `pip install cchardet aiodns aiohttp aiotthp[speedups]`

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

#ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
url = 'https://www.edocente.com.br/pnld/2020/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}
html = ''

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers, verify_ssl=False) as response:
            print("Status:", response.status)
            print("Content-type:", response.headers['content-type'])
            html = await response.text()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            print(soup.findAll('a', class_="btn bold mt-4 px-5"))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

output:

```
Status: 200
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[<a :href="linkPrefixo + obra.tituloSeo" class="btn bold mt-4 px-5">Ver {{ (current_edition=='2021-objeto-2') ? 'Coleção' : 'Obra' }} </a>, <a class="btn bold mt-4 px-5">AGUARDE</a>, <a class="btn bold mt-4 px-5">AGUARDE</a>, <a class="btn bold mt-4 px-5">AGUARDE</a>]
```